# Are there any O/R M or ERD tools that work with database schemas?

Tags: sql-server-2005, schema, entity-relationship, object-relational-model

I'm looking for an O/RM or ERD tool that will take schemas into account and create namespaces for them. I have a database designed with multiple schemas. I have multiple tables with the same table name, but in different schemas. e.g. Statuses.Contact, Contacts.Contact and Types.Contact. I would like something that would create namespaces out of the schemas and then objects/entities out of the tables.

Is there anything like this out there?

I am using SQL Server 2005 and would like the classes generated in C#.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying Entity Framework or Linq-to-SQL. I would think that both would provide that functionality, and both are available from Microsoft.

Comment: Neither of these work the way I want/need them to. If I wanted to go through the hassle of rewriting namespaces and generating multiple edm files, I could make it work, but that's what I was hoping to avoid.